# Twilio available phone search by prefix

Tags: twilio

How do I search for phone number by prefix using the API? The Twilio "Buy A Number" tool lets you search for begins with term, but I don't see a way to do it using the API.

You can do:

```
AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local?Contains=703%
```

But that still finds numbers with 703 anywhere, not just the prefix. Only way I can see to do this is using the * single number search, a la:

```
AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local?Contains=703*******
```

But then how do I make that generic to any country? Have a lookup table of phone number lengths for every country so I can add the appropriate number of *'s?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio provides this information in their API docs ([Find phone numbers by number pattern](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-get-basic-example-2)).

For example using PHP:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACde6f132a3c49700934481addd5ce1659"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
        "Contains" => "510555****"
    ));
foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I covered that in my question. To do that method, you have to know the number length for padding, which varies country by country.

How do I generically do it for any country? Contains=703% looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: You always need the country code, you cant search without it. So you can't do a global search as you propose.

Comment: Country code is fine, but I'm looking for a generic way to search by number prefix. If I'm searching US, I can search for 703*******. But if I search another country that has a 6 digit phone, or an 11 digit phone, that won't work, and there's no way to know that except building some 300 entry lookup table with phone number length. Even that might not work if a country has multiple possible number lengths. I'm looking for a way to do Contains 703% to search a prefix, like the "starts with" search in the Twilio console. Looks like there's no way, or % is bugged.