# Twilio API PHP list available Phone numbers for purchase API Version 5.X

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am looking for a little assistance on listing available phone numbers for purchase using Twilios API and PHP for their 5.X API Verison. Below is the error I get and the PHP im using. Im sure im just overlooking something:

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /twilio-php-app/findnumbers.php on line 16
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /twilio-php-app/findnumbers.php on line 16

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$token = "removed";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);


$numbers = $client->availablePhoneNumbers('US')->local->read(
array("areaCode" => "513")
);

foreach($numbers->availablephonenumbers as $number) {
echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

If I echo $numbers I find it is an array. Here is the raw output where I just want to get the "phone_number": "xxxxxx" output; minus the "phone_number": part.

[output of array Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Sq3.png)

Adding to this, if I run the PHP as the following; I get single number outputs

```
$numbers = $client->availablePhoneNumbers('US')->local->read(
array("areaCode" => "513")
);

echo $numbers[1]->phoneNumber;
```

Changing the value of [1] to [2] grabs the next phone number. How can I loop this?

Comment: `$numbers` is not an object. i assume `$client->availablePhoneNumbers` doesnt return what you think it does.

Comment: Im looking to list all available numbers that can purchased. I based this on some version 4.x code I found on here which apparently works, as its referenced a few times elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055441/twilio-available-phone-search-by-prefix

Do you have any recommendations on how to accomplish this? 

Here's the doc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be done 100% correct but I found a solution that increases the count of the array based on count and stacks the numbers nicely.

Sharing this in case anyone else ever comes across this and needs help; this does exactly what its intended to.... Search the twilio databse for available numbers to purchase, based on criteria

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "your_SID";
$token = "Your_Token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$numbers = $client->availablePhoneNumbers('US')->local->read(
array("areaCode" => "513")
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); ++$i) {
print $numbers[$i]->phoneNumber . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. One thing you might want to try with your original code is to call `toArray` on the available numbers before looping over them. Like `foreach($numbers->availablephonenumbers-toArray() as $number) {`. Let me know if that helps too.

Comment: Is there any way i can view both local and tollfree number in same request?

Answer (score -1):

Just an observation, but you are already using the availablePhoneNumbers method on $client when you say `$numbers = $client->availablePhoneNumbers...`

Perhaps, in the foreach, you just need to reference `$numbers` and not `$numbers->availablephonenumbers`?

Comment: im not sure that will work as im trying to echo out the "phone_number". I did run it and got this:

#0/twilio-php-app/findnumbers.php(17): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\AvailablePhoneNumberCountry\LocalInstance->__get('phone_number')
#1 {main} thrown in /twilio-php-app/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AvailablePhoneNumberCountry/LocalInstance.php on line 83